# Convert json_objects to array

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT json_object('image_name', image_name, 'iid', iid) 
FROM `posts_images` 
WHERE `pid` = '62'
```

That result in this

Image:
[image]

can I convert these result into one line JSON array in same query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
$query = "SELECT json_object('image_name', image_name, 'iid', iid) FROM `posts_images` WHERE `pid` = '62'";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: im not asking for php ,, i want it in mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4"};

var arr = $.map(o, function(el) { return el; })

console.log(arr)
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

**I figure it out**

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    '[',  
            GROUP_CONCAT(json_object('image_name', image_name, 'iid', iid)),
    ']'
) 
FROM posts_images WHERE pid = '62'
```

> [{"iid": 99, "image_name": "6_1499203101812.jpg"},{"iid": 98,
>   "image_name": "6_1499203101708.jpg"},{"iid": 97, "image_name":
>   "6_1499203101651.jpg"},{"iid": 96, "image_name":
>   "6_1499203101574.jpg"},{"iid": 95, "image_name":
>   "6_1499203101472.jpg"},{"iid": 100, "image_name":
>   "6_1499203101886.jpg"},{"iid": 101, "image_name":
>   "6_1499203101960.jpg"},{"iid": 102, "image_name":
>   "6_1499203102020.jpg"}]